# Adobe Flash Player won't update

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash-player

When I go to [Adobe - Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) website, it tells me that I have 11,0,1,148 version of Flash Player installed on my Chrome yet 10.3.183.10 version is available and when I go to [Adobe - Install Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) it tells me:

```
Your Google Chrome browser already includes Adobe® Flash® Player built-in. Google Chrome will automatically update when new versions of Flash Player are available.
```

any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you have the current version of Chrome then you have the current version of Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: @Ramhound I think that OP expects to see flash website report the version number of newest flash when being accessed from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome you havn't to worry about your flash player version. Google Chrome has flash built-in (and auto-updates it). Therefore it is not possible and not neccessary to update the flash player separately.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the latest version, may be you must have landed on some old flash plugin version page.

For Chrome help check this out : [Click Here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=108086)

Adobe Flash is directly integrated with Google Chrome and enabled by default. Any available updates for Adobe Flash are automatically included in Google Chrome system updates.

To check the latest version of adobe flash : [Click Here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

For other OS : [Click Here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)

Currently it shows latest version of Adobe Flash Player is **11.0.1.152**